# stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`cs723.mojohost.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'

Tags: php, email

We are attempting to send an autoresponder email to new members.  We're using the same configuration on other sites on the same server with no issue. Upon sending the email the following error is returned:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`cs723.mojohost.com` did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net`

https://gyazo.com/ffb0cb7645d51ed21ecc863f1e3196b2

We're using Laravel with connecting to:
smtp.sendgrid.net 
port - 587 
encription using TLS

We have tried the following with no success:

- port options 25 & 2525 (returns a different error https://gyazo.com/3d42107c6aa66acc2fbe582b3a6a352e)
- reconfigured Laravel to send `AUTH` command before `MAIL FROM` command (returns same different error 250)

Additionally we are unable to connect via PUTTY. We verified the SSH permissions are correct with MojoHost.

I've read in a different post that

> The correct fix for this is to replace the invalid, misconfigured or self-signed certificate with a good one.

Attempted that with no success either.  Hoping someone can provide some helpful insight. Going on a week now of trying to solve this....

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 15):

Disable "SMTP Restrictions" from WHM.

For context, If you don't use WHM/Cpanel for your server management this is would not be applicable to you. If you do, in WHM on the left navigation menu, just type "SMTP" and you'll see SMTP Restrictions as the top choice on results. Click on it and there is a disable/enable toggle button.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to your answer?

Comment: Thanks this worked! @marcogmonteiro For context, If you don't use WHM/Cpanel for your server management this is would not be applicable to you. If you do, in WHM on the left navigation menu, just type "SMTP" and you'll see SMTP Restrictions as the top choice on results. Click on it and there is a disable/enable toggle button.

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia thanks, added that to the answer so others can get to it more easily.

Answer (score 12):

In the method createSmtpDriver from

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager.php

it fetches the key stream from

> \config\mail.php

that is later used as custom options for the stream_context_create method inside

> \vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php.

So to set the keys verify_peer, verify_peer_name, and allow_self_signed to solve the error mentioned by the OP you can add the following to the \config\mail.php:

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

Comment: This is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people upgrading to PHP 5.6+ are running into the following error:

ErrorException: Email to [email address] failed: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=[hostname]' did not match expected CN=[target hostname]' - library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:206

As of PHP 5.6 peer verification is enabled by default (http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php).

If you are running WHM or Plesk, I found the issue could be resolved as follows:

WHM: Change the “Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak)” from “On” to “Off”.

Plesk: Create a new subscription with the URL set as the server host address, then assign it a SSL cert via the lets encrypt plugin.

Answer (score 2):

for laravel add this line in .env file to unset mail encryption

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = NULL
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then this way, the emails won't get encrypted and someone might intercept the emails to get all the information that's in there.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
```

, or

```
MAIL_DRIVER = sendmail
```

Comment: or 
MAIL_DRIVER = sendmail

Comment: In your `config/mail.php` configuration file, check the `default` option to see what the actual environment key is. In mine (Laravel 9+) it's "MAIL_MAILER".

Answer (score 1):

Try unsetting encryption by removing 'tls' in \config/mail.php if you are using Non-SSL Settings

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),

Comment: We tried that already with no success.   We have since moved away from SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

for who use mail hosting at cpanel, you can use my solution. I have tried and it works with out changing anything in `config\mail.php` as stated by Chaibi Alaa answer.

So my apps architecture is from VM instance at GCP -> CloudFlare -> Mail Hosting (CPANEL Based). the problems comes with the certification

```
CN=`*.abc' did not match expected CN=`mail.def.com'
```

so instead of changing vendor code, i tried to bypassing the cloudflare. so I'm pointing out directly to the mail hosting DNS.

here is example of my configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhosting.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME="noreply@def.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

In my case it works, hopefully it would help someone else which facing same issue. Please take a notes, I always trying to avoid workaround solution (by changing vendor code -> could be harmfull, do it with your own risk unless you know what you do)

you can find your MAIL_HOST in the `Mail Client Manual Settings` if you use `Roundcube`

Answer (score 0):

```
 'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
            'stream'     => [
                'ssl' => [
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    'verify_peer'       => false,   // <-------------- this is the important part 
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        
        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],
```