# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "yea****" using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to set up email for a Laravel project using SendGrid.
When following their documentation I get an error (https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/laravel.html)

The `.env` looks like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yea****
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
```

The error i get looks like this

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`****.****.***' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'


/home/myusername/public_html/api/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php
    public function startTLS()
            {
                // STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT only allow tls1.0 connections (some php versions)
                // To support modern tls we allow explicit tls1.0, tls1.1, tls1.2
                // Ssl3 and older are not allowed because they are vulnerable
                // @TODO make tls arguments configurable
                return stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->stream, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_0_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT);
            }

        Arguments
        "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`****.****.***' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'"
```

I fixed this error by using the code provided in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315825).
I know this is bad practice but i got another error.

```
Swift_TransportException
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "yea****" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data " in /home/myusername/public_html/a[i/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:456 Stack trace: #0 

/home/myusername/public_html/api/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php
$message = 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "'.$this->username.'" using '.$count.' possible authenticators.';
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $message .= ' Authenticator '.$error[0].' returned '.$error[1].'.';
            }
            throw new Swift_TransportException($message);
        }
    }
```

This looks like some kind of authentication error to me, I am using the same credentials i use to login to the SendGrid dashboard.

any ideas on how to fix these problems?

Comment: What are you using as a hosting provider?

Comment: I am using a cPanel VPS at [TransIp](https://www.transip.nl/)

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this case was double-quote the username, password and port number.

Then I got another error, like this:

'''
   Connection to tcp://smtp.hostx.com:465 Timed Out
'''

```
   Connection to tcp://smtp.hostx.com:465 Timed Out
```

and I fix it changing MAIL_ENCRYPTION from ***tls*** to ***ssl***:

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

I hope this helps someone else due to this post is too old.