# "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`gains.nanosupercloud.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'" in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm working in mail in laravel. I've following configuration.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=********
MAIL_PASSWORD=########
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I've already tried this one but not working

[stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`cs723.mojohost.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554028/stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate-cn-cs723-mojohost-com-did-not)

And many more similar question but still i don't get the solution. I've following error:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`gains.nanosupercloud.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Here is the code used for email sending.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->from(\Config::get('values.app_email'),\Config::get('values.app_name'))
                ->subject('Successfully approved your Company')
                ->greeting(sprintf('Hello %s', $this->user->name))
                ->line('Your company has been approved successfully. Now, it will be visible to our website');
}
```

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

**Note: Everything works perfectly in local server(ubantu 16.04)**

Comment: Same error for me while it is working perfectly in the local environment. @SagarGautam did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Ishaan It was issue of using sendgrid in server. Use the server email account for sending emails it will work perfectly

Comment: So you mean, to change the `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` from `.env` file ?

Comment: @Ishaan yes and other variables too in mail configuration

Comment: So ultimately we are not sending emails from sendgrid anymore?

Comment: @Ishaan I don't know about new configuration. It may be some server issue

Answer (score 12):

The answer i am giving may look funny but i have same error while sending mail in the live server

just change this

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

I don't know the reason How the hell is this working but it works fine for me

Comment: I've tried this before but still gives some problem. Error is : `proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons`

Comment: I think i may be blocked port of the `website `Please Contact `Your Hosting Provider or `Rise the support ticket to them`  Can You Please Share the screen Shot of the error You are getting So that i may Help You

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, what I did was change the

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

And then clear cache with

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And everything went well

Answer (score 2):

add this line in .env file to disable mail encryption

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

using laravel 7 and deployed on godaddys shared hosting.

just put this data in .env file and problem is solved

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME="****@domain.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="tls"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="****@domain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

It's the same happening with me. In local it's working fine but in the live server as am using the GoDaddy server same issue is araising continuously. but finally, it works. here are my codes below for the .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=abc.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=info@abc.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Hope it will work for you.