# Laravel Mail Works Fine Locally, Broken Hosted

Tags: laravel

I have created a Laravel site locally, and all works perfectly fine, however now that it is on a hosted server, I am having problems with my email facility. 
When you register as a user, the site should send you a welcome email, and bring you to a page that tells you that you are now logged in. Instead, no email is sent and you are eventually taken to a blank screen, however the sign up is successful. This is my code.

Register Controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),  
    ]);

    Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

WelcomeMail.php

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.welcome');
}
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=*username*
MAIL_PASSWORD=*password*
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@jonathanmarsden.one
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Jonathan Marsden"
```

Has anyone come across this problem before, if so how did you solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984440/8487424

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mailtrap which is only used for testing purposes only. To get a real email to your gmail account or other account,  you should be using some other MAIL_HOST such as smtp.gmail.com or sendgrid or whatever. Let me know if you need help afterwards.

Comment: Thankyou, I will try with the one.com email admin that I have set up. The problem with that though is you are only given server and port, would the username just be the email address and password be null?

Comment: For example, If using gmail smtp, you should use your email as your username in your .env file.  but for MAIL_PASSWORD , you need to do the following. go to My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google, enable two step verification and generate the app password. this will be your MAIL_PASSWORD. who knows what some other smtps work. I gave you an example of gmail smtp.

Comment: Okay that's great, I will use gmail as you suggested. Thankyou

Comment: If you don't plan on sending so many emails per minute or second or day, you can use gmail. I use sendgrid's smtp , but I also pay for each email, but the fee is so cheap. Free gmail account has its limits ,maybe 500 email per day or month. I don't know exactly.

Comment: It is only for a uni project so gmail will be perfect as there won't be much traffic and many emails being sent. Thanks for your help.